# Asynchronus Infinite scrolling to display data in table view in reacts app

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, infinite-scroll

I am developing my first reacts application, I go through various reacts plugins for data grid with infinite scroll option but didn't get proper solution.

What I have and What I need is:

- I am fetching the users list from 3rd party API.
- At a time only 50 users records fetch via API.
- I have around 10000 users records and need to display first_name, last_name, email with Edit/Delete link in table view.
- I need to append the next 50 users in the list when user scroll the window/div and it will happen till all the records are displayed.
- I also need the **sorting and searching** option on first_name so that user can sort/search the user by first_name. It also needs to be done via ajax request to 3rd party API.

Please suggest me the good reactjs component/plugins to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid), it's full of features and really simple to use

Comment: Yes I have already look on that and it looks its working perfect only in case when all data is fetched on 1 API call. But my API returns only 50 records at a time and I need to 50 records each time (till all the records fetched) when user scroll down the window or div. Also I need the sorting/filtering via the AJAX request to API's which I think I can done with this plugin.

Comment: Well, I don't see any problems in doing what you need. You can keep making the ajax request to get the other 50 records and add them to the grid. About the filter, probably it's filtering only the frontend, so you would need to make a different request, with a custom filter if you want to get the ajax return with different results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) and working fine. Easy to implement.